# Custom code on the updateHandler from HKWorkoutSession

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

My question is plain and simple. Can i run custom code in the updateHandler when I´ve executed a HKWorkoutSession and is listening for HeartRate samples? (Even when the Watch is locked from "wrist down" movement)
If this i possible what are my limitations?

I´m interested in processing the HeartRate data when my code receives them. I don´t have a device yet so I haven't been able to test it yet.

Would love your thoughts on this if anyone have experimented with an actual device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do this, I've had it append every HKSample that came back from my query onto an array, so when I resume the array is much larger. However UI won't update this way, on resume you need to update to the values you've received from the updateHandler.

Whether I *should* be doing this, or how far it can be pushed, I'm not sure.

**Update**

In the latest Xcode 7 beta you can get simulated workout data, so you won't need to install the Watch OS 2 beta on your device.